# subfigures with revtex?

Tags: subfloats, revtex, incompatibility

I'm writing an article using the `revtex4` document class, but it appears to be incompatible with `subfig` (which also seems to be loading `caption`). How can I title some subfigures in my `revtex4` document?

The following minimal example shows how just loading `subfig` breaks the formatting of figures as defined by the document class.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{revtex4}
% Uncomment the following line to see the problem
%\usepackage{subfig}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
  \framebox[5cm]{\raisebox{3cm}{}}
\caption{Some dummy title for my figure which should be long enough 
         to occupy at least a couple of lines, and maybe even a bit
         more. That's good.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Furthermore, the `caption` package complains with the following warning

```
Package caption Warning: \caption will not be redefined since it's already
(caption)                redefined by a document class or package which is
(caption)                unknown to the caption package.
See the caption package documentation for explanation.
```

So the question is, how could I solve this problem? Is there an alternative to `subfig` which I could use together with `revtex4`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could load the subfig package with the option `caption=false`:, e.g.:

`\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}`

This prevents loading of the caption package. (caption3.sty will still be loaded, but this does not make harm since this file only provides some macros needed by the subfig package, especially it does not alter any captions.)

See subfig package documentation for details.

Comment: Nice! That does seems to solve the problem.

Comment: Can you please type a minimal working example? Same problem, your solution isn't working. Why RevTex makes it so difficult, I don't know.