# subfigure and subfig packages deprecated

Tags: floats, subfloats, best-practices

I was using the `subfigure` package to align multiple small images in a document. However, WikiBooks states that "the `subfigure` and `subfig` packages are deprecated and shouldn't be used any more" ([WikiBooks Floats, Figures and Captions](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions#Subfloats)).

What is the alternative/proper option to achieve the same result?

Comment: Afaik, only `subfigure` is deprecated and `subfig` is the way to go instead.

Comment: `subfig` isn't deprecated!. You can also use `subcaption` which provides `subfigure`.

Comment: I've written tens of times that `subfig` is only deprecated by *one* (albeit respectable) guide. The package `subcaption` has better features, perhaps, but `subfig` remains invaluable with classes such as RevTeX4 that are *not* compatible with `caption` (which is required by `subcaption`).

Comment: Thank you, I will try `subfig` and `subcaption` then! =)

Comment: @egreg Can you post up an answer explaining this and what the updsides of each are? As I recall, you explained this to me less then a week ago.

Comment: Some slightly related article from the TUGboat "Side-by-side gures in LaTeX": http://tug.org/TUGboat/tb34-1/tb106thurnherr.pdf

Comment: @egreg, also I couldn't make `subcaption` work with Beamer, although `subfig` works.

Comment: subfig isn't deprecated but quickly becoming so as there is no active support for it.

Comment: @usr1234567 The answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/144951/2574 is up-to-date, and furthermore there were no recent changes regarding these packages: `subfig` is still version 1.3 from 2005, and the user interface of `subcaption` hasn't changed since 2011, I (as maintainer of `subcaption`) only have done bugfixing in the last 5 years.

Comment: BTW: I do not understand all the fuzz about avoiding "deprecated" packages. The LaTeX2e world is full of abandoned packages, and most of them are still working fine and used by many people. Of course, it would be nice if someone would fix known bugs, but often there is a workaround or patch available on the net. (And the same is true for packages offered by the LaTeX2e team itself!) And both, `subfigure` and `subfig` are fine and easy-to-use packages, and beside the broken `hyperref` compatibility of `subfig`, I see no reason of not still using them today.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was able to avoid `subfig` completely.
Used [The Subﬁg Package documentation](http://www.pvv.ntnu.no/~berland/latex/docs/subfig.pdf): *"Do You Need This Package?"*

```
\begin{figure}%
\centering
\parbox{1.2in}{...figure code...}%
\qquad
\begin{minipage}{1.2in}%
...figure code...
\end{minipage}%
\caption{Here are two figures side-by-side.}%
\label{fig:1figs}%
\end{figure}
```

Thanks for the info! I'm sure it will be even more useful as I dig into the package more.

Comment: I realize that I'm not very knowledgable in (La)TeX, but I am really confused now. You avoided subfig by using subfig??

Comment: Add the word "documentation". =) Used the subfig docs.

Comment: However, this does not add captions, which might be desired.

Answer (score 40):

There are at least four classes that aren't compatible with `caption` (hence with `subcaption`), whereas `subfig` is a substitute when called as

```
\usepackage[caption=false]{subfig}
```

1. The `ws-proc9x6` class (and related ones by the same publisher), see [how to get the ws-procs9x6 document class to work with subcaption package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96496/how-to-get-the-ws-procs9x6-document-class-to-work-with-subcaption-package/96548#96548)
2. `tufte-book` and the other similar classes, see [Problem with tufte-book and subfigure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/87364/problem-with-tufte-book-and-subfigure/87366#87366)
3. `IEEEtran`, see [2-col floats and citation order problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/64664/2-col-floats-and-citation-order-problem/64700#64700)
4. REVTeX, see [subfigures with revtex?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22388/subfigures-with-revtex)

It's true that `subfig` doesn't cooperate well with `hyperref`, but when the alternative is no subfloats at all …

---

Related subfloat discussion is also given in [subcaption vs. subfig: Best package for referencing a subfigure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13625/subcaption-vs-subfig-best-package-for-referencing-a-subfigure)

Comment: `subfig` is simpler, I find. If you don't need what `caption` offers or the complexities and sophistication of `subcaption`, `subfig` often works well.

Comment: @cfr What do you mean by "simpler"? "Simpler to use"? The syntax of `\subcaptionbox` (by `subcaption`) is similar to `\subfloat` (by `subfig`). "Simpler implementation"? No, the major part of the `caption` package is inside `caption3.sty` and this is loaded by `subfig`, too, even when using `caption=false`. The rest of `subfig` is handling the counters and duplicated code while the `(sub)caption` package tries to use as much code as possible for both, captions and sub-captions. So if you want a real lightweight solution without all the `caption` stuff, you need to use `subfigure`.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt Simpler to understand and to use. `subcaption`'s documentation requires more effort to navigate. Not necessarily more difficult, but certainly trickier and more time-consuming. `subfig` is relatively straightforward to figure out and utilise. This is not a criticism of `subcaption`. It is pretty much to be expected given that `subcaption` is more powerful/flexible than `subfig`. But if you don't need that power and flexibility, `subfig` is often easier.

Comment: @cfr Thanks for the feedback. I'm not really happy with the documentation either, and am currently rewriting the caption bundle doc., but unfortunately progress is rather slow...

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt Documentation is *hard*. Really hard.