# How to left align caption inside subtable?

Tags: tables, captions

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}

% things needed to include figures
\usepackage{subfigure, graphicx}
% float must be included for the [H] to actually work
\usepackage{float}
% formulas
\usepackage{amsmath}
% Added to adjust captions
\usepackage[singlelinecheck=false]{caption}
% added to adjust margins at the suggestion of Dr. Matt
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{fullpage}

\begin{document}
% 2 column side by side table
\begin{table}[H]
  \subtable[Half-life for $^{108}$Ag] {%

    % -----------------------------------------------------%
    \begin{tabular}{c@{\hskip 1cm} c}
      \hline\noalign{\smallskip}
      Accepted $T_{1/2}$ & Experimental $T_{1/2}$\\
      (s) & (s)\\
      \hline\noalign{\smallskip}
      142.92 & 158 $\pm$ 7\\
      \hline\noalign{\smallskip}
    \end{tabular}
    \label{lefttable}
    % -----------------------------------------------------%

  }
  \subtable[Half-life for $^{110}$Ag] {%

    % -----------------------------------------------------%
    \begin{tabular}{c@{\hskip 1cm} c}
      \hline\noalign{\smallskip}
      Accepted $T_{1/2}$ & Experimental $T_{1/2}$\\
      (s) & (s)\\
      \hline\noalign{\smallskip}
      24.6 & 21 $\pm$ 2\\
      \hline\noalign{\smallskip}
    \end{tabular}
    \label{righttable}
    % -----------------------------------------------------%

  }
  \caption{2 Column tables side by side}
  \label{sidebysidetable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

That produces this result:
[image]

I'd like the captions to be left aligned. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Please make your code compilable, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to help you. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: I doesn't seem tedious to me, this helps streamline the process, thanks for the reminder. I edited my original post.

Comment: Yes, exactly :) Thanks for understanding. Others don't get the idea this fast, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

To your question:

`subcaption` package supports the `caption` package and use its `\captionsetup` interface.

```
    \usepackage{caption}
      \captionsetup[table]{justification=raggedright}
      \captionsetup[subtable]{justification=raggedright}
```

where `raggedright` is left aligned.

In the problem [subfigure-and-subfig-packages-deprecated](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144782/subfigure-and-subfig-packages-deprecated), `subcaption` is recommended.

```
\usepackage{subcaption}
```

instead of `subfigure`.

And I change your subtable environment style:

```
\begin{table}[H]
  \begin{subtable}[b]{0.48\textwidth}
    % -----------------------------------------------------%
    \caption{Half-life for $^{108}$Ag} \label{lefttable}
    \begin{tabular}{c@{\hskip 1cm} c}
      \hline\noalign{\smallskip}
      Accepted $T_{1/2}$ & Experimental $T_{1/2}$\\
      (s) & (s)\\
      \hline\noalign{\smallskip}
      142.92 & 158 $\pm$ 7\\
      \hline\noalign{\smallskip}
    \end{tabular}
    % -----------------------------------------------------%  
  \end{subtable}
  \begin{subtable}[b]{0.48\textwidth}
    % -----------------------------------------------------%
    \caption{Half-life for $^{110}$Ag}     \label{righttable}
    \begin{tabular}{c@{\hskip 1cm} c}
      \hline\noalign{\smallskip}
      Accepted $T_{1/2}$ & Experimental $T_{1/2}$\\
      (s) & (s)\\
      \hline\noalign{\smallskip}
      24.6 & 21 $\pm$ 2\\
      \hline\noalign{\smallskip}
    \end{tabular}
    % -----------------------------------------------------%
  \end{subtable}
  \caption{2 Column tables side by side}
  \label{sidebysidetable}
\end{table}
```

And output is 
[image]

Noting that the overall width (lefttable + righttable) should be less than `\textwidth`.
And the option in `[b]` is vertical position for that sub-table. In your case, same height tables would make `b` and `t` no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Using `\hspace*{\fill}` inside the subcaption, as in

```
\caption{This table. \hspace*{\fill}}
```

worked for me. Here's the working example based off of the other posts (see the inline comments for use of `\hspace`):

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{caption, subcaption}
\usepackage[top=1in, bottom=1in, left=1in, right=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H]
  \begin{subtable}[b]{0.48\textwidth}
    \caption{Half-life for $^{108}$Ag \hspace*{\fill}} %NOTE 
    \begin{tabular}{c@{\hskip 1cm} c}
      \hline\noalign{\smallskip}
      Accepted $T_{1/2}$ & Experimental $T_{1/2}$\\
      (s) & (s)\\
      \hline\noalign{\smallskip}
      142.92 & 158 $\pm$ 7\\
      \hline\noalign{\smallskip}
    \end{tabular}
  \end{subtable}
  \begin{subtable}[b]{0.48\textwidth}
    \caption{Half-life for $^{110}$Ag \hspace*{\fill}} %NOTE
    \begin{tabular}{c@{\hskip 1cm} c}
      \hline\noalign{\smallskip}
      Accepted $T_{1/2}$ & Experimental $T_{1/2}$\\
      (s) & (s)\\
      \hline\noalign{\smallskip}
      24.6 & 21 $\pm$ 2\\
      \hline\noalign{\smallskip}
    \end{tabular}
  \end{subtable}
  \caption{2 Column tables side by side}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```