# Trying to change from subfigure package to subcaption

Tags: subfloats, subcaption

I am working with a template that uses the package subfigure, as I understand that it is outdated (and also because I have problem understanding how to place to figures side by side using this package), I try to change into subcaption package, but it gives me the following error:

```
Package caption Error: The `subcaption' package does not work correctly(caption) in compatibility mode. \begin{document}
```

Anyone knows this problem?

The packages that I use are:

```
\usepackage{jcappub}
\usepackage{dcolumn}% Align table columns on decimal point
%\usepackage[reqno]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{bm}% bold math
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{txfonts}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
% \usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{wasysym}
```

Comment: Have you seen this? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144782/subfigure-and-subfig-packages-deprecated maybe it will help? It is hard for people to answer the question without knowing what class document and other packages you are using.

Comment: The two packages have different syntaxes for subfigures, if you could show us your code we would be able to see what you've done wrong.

Comment: Strange, on a different computer it does not gives me this same error and work with subcaption package..

Comment: Did you empty all temp files before re-compiling?