# how to reduce the space between subfigures with \subfigure

Tags: spacing, subfloats

I want to put figures in rows, but the vertical space between sub-images is too large, how can I reduce the space between them?

Note: The template uses `\usepackage{subfigure}`, so it cannot use `\usepackage{subcaption}`

The code is there:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering   

\subfigure[]{\label{fig:test1}\includegraphics[width=100mm]{test1.jpg}}

\subfigure[]{\label{fig:test2}\includegraphics[width=100mm]{test2.jpg}}

\caption{The space is too large}

\end{figure}
```

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: `subfigure` is deprecated, use `subfig` instead please, see also http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144782/subfigure-and-subfig-packages-deprecated

Comment: I use `subfig` - I've just tried a basic example myself and I don't get anything like the amount of space you do and I don't have any special settings. Have you got any whitespace included around your graphics that you need to clip (add `, clip=true` inside the square brackets)? Of course, `subfig` might do things differently from `subfigure` but as stated above you should probably switch.

Comment: Did you give a try at the `floatrow` package? It also can manage sideways captions, a row can be either a row of figures or a row of subfigures, and it cooperates with the `caption` package.

Comment: Hi, the images should be fine and no white space included.

Comment: I tried to use subfig, but the template doesn't allow to do so. I have done a lot of work with this template, so it is better not to change the template. Any other tips will be appreciated.

Comment: @Leo: Please provide a MWE as already asked from you, otherwise any help is `looking into a chrystal ball` and guess what might be the cause ;-)

Comment: Try loading `subfigure` with the `tight` option: `\usepackage[tight]{subfigure}`. Does that reduce the space?