# How to hide subcaptions but retain subref labels?

Tags: floats, cross-referencing, subcaption

In this example, I would like to remove the text displayed by the command `\subcaption{\label{left} Left half}` (as well as `\subcaption{\label{right} Right half}`). However I would still need the labels `left` and `right` to work in the text.

The reason for this is that I have a complex array of subfigures that I create as a single image file, and which includes the labels "a", "b", etc in the image itself.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}

\begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}
\subcaption{\label{left} Left half}
\end{minipage}
\begin{minipage}{0.25\textwidth}
\subcaption{\label{right} Right half}
\end{minipage}

\caption{\label{figure} Overall caption}
\end{figure}

Figure~\ref{figure} has \ref{left} on the left, and \ref{right} on the right,
also known as \subref{left} and \subref{right}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Compliments on an outstanding minimum working example (MWE)!

Comment: @Mico Although this might cost me the upvotes, I have to admit my MWE is adapted (viz. 99% copied) from another question on this very site (the question was related but not the same).

Comment: Nothing wrong with adapting existing code! :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you (a) use `subfigure` environments instead of `minipage` environments, (b) assign zero width to the `subfigure` environments, and -- most importantly -- (c) use `\refstepcounter` directives instead of `caption` directives to increment the counter named `subfigure` without generating any text. The `\label` directives should remain in place, of course.

Doing so will print out the overall caption below the composite graph and generate the following sentence:

> Figure 1 has 1a on the left and 1b on the right, also known as a and b.

In case you're wondering what's going on here: LaTeX's `\caption` directive not only typesets its argument as the caption text (duh), it also invokes a `\refstepcounter` instruction to increment the counter (called `subfigure`) associated with the current float. It's this counter that the `\label` instruction needs to find and latch on to.

It's also worth mentioning that the `subcaption` package actually provides a dedicated macro called `\phantomsubcaption` for exactly your use case, *viz.*, not wanting to produce a subcaption-related text while preserving the ability to create cross-references to the subfloat(s). `\phantomsubcaption` (essentially) performs the instruction `\refstepcounter{subfigure}` for you. Use `\phantomsubcaption` in lieu of `\refstepcounter{subfigure}` if you prefer. In fact, if you wish to use `\phantomsubcaption`, it's not actually necessary to set up zero-width subfigure environments; just enclose the `\phantomsubcaption` and `\label` statements in a TeX group, like so:

```
    {\phantomsubcaption\label{left} \phantomsubcaption\label{right}}
```

---

A full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}%
% We now insert 2 zero-width 'subfigure' environments 
% to the **right** of the graph. By encasing the
% '\refstepcounter{...}\label{...}' statements inside
% 'subfigure' environments, the subsequent '\subref' 
% instructions will generate the expected output.
\begin{subfigure}{0\textwidth}
\refstepcounter{subfigure}\label{left}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{0\textwidth}
\refstepcounter{subfigure}\label{right}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{Overall caption}\label{figure} 
\end{figure}

Figure~\ref{figure} has \ref{left} on the left and \ref{right} on the right,
also known as \subref{left} and \subref{right}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Isn't `subfigure` deprecated ? [see here, for example](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/144782/), but I've seen that on other places. Not a rant, I used to use it a lot, but I'm confused now...

Comment: @kebs - Are you maybe confusing the *package* called `subfigure` -- which is indeed deprecated -- with the *environment* called `subfigure`, which is provided by the `subcaption` package?  Observe that neither my code nor that of the OP loads the deprecated `subfigure` package.

Comment: I added my answer because I hadn't seen your mention of `\phantomsubcaption`. Nice with an explanation (so +1), but why didn't you use `\phantomsubcaption` in the code? I for one would never go the trouble of the zero-width subfigures if I knew of `\phantomsubcaption`, so why highlight that method?

Comment: @Mico oops, correct, I indeed thought it was about the package, thanks.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. - I had a hunch the OP might like receiving an explanation of "what goes on under the hood". :-) Actually, I thought it might be interesting to elaborate a bit on the deeper connection between `\caption` on the one hand and `\label` on the other by way of `\refstepcounter` (which, in turn, though not mentioned explicitly in my answer, invokes `\@currentlabel`). I admit it may have been too much of a good thing. I'll go ahead and add a paragraph about how to use `\phantomcaption` without setting up `subfigure` environments.

Comment: I have no problem with opening the hood, but I think it might be better to first say "use `\phantomsubcaption` like this: `<code example>`" (something like what I did in my answer), and then go on to say "to understand what is going on, ... `<second code example>`".  (Not necessarily with those exact words of course.)

Comment: @TorbjørnT. - I'll be more to point next time... :-)

Answer (score 5):

This is what `\phantomsubcaption` is for. Note that the phantom subcaptions has to be in a group of their own, hence the pair of braces around them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}

{\phantomsubcaption\label{left}
\phantomsubcaption\label{right}}

\caption{\label{figure} Overall caption}
\end{figure}

Figure~\ref{figure} has \ref{left} on the left, and \ref{right} on the right,
also known as \subref{left} and \subref{right}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I accepted @Mico's answer b/c it gives more context.

Comment: @astabada You haven't accepted any answers yet. Upvoting (clicking the up-arrow) means "this answer was useful", accepting (clicking the checkmark below the arrows) usually indicates that this is the solution used in the end. That said, I think I'll delete my answer, because I see Mico mentioned `\phantomsubcaption` in his answer as well, before I added mine. (It's just a bit of a mystery to me why he chose to use the really cumbersome way with the `\refstepcounter` when he knew of `\phantomsubcaption`.)